# SWTableViewCell slide programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, slide

How can i slide programmatically SWTableViewCell.

```
//When i click in a cell i want to open the swtableviewcell
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  ???
}
```

i have tried:

```
 [[[SWTableViewCell alloc]init]didTransitionToState:2];
```

and in swtableviewcell.m

```
-(void)didTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state{
NSLog(@"state: %lu",state);
if (_cellState == kCellStateCenter)
{
    [self.cellScrollView setContentOffset:[self contentOffsetForCellState:kCellStateRight] animated:YES];
    [self.delegate swipeableTableViewCell:self scrollingToState:kCellStateRight];
}
```

}

but is not correct. Can you help me?

Thanks,
Mikel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to be able to show the utility buttons when a table view cell was selected so I added a method in SWTableViewCell.m

```
-(void)showUtilityButtonsAnimated:(BOOL)animated {    
// Force the scroll back to run on the main thread because of weird scroll view bugs
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.cellScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
});
_cellState = kCellStateLeft;

if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(swipeableTableViewCell:scrollingToState:)])
{
    [self.delegate swipeableTableViewCell:self scrollingToState:kCellStateCenter];
}
```

}

and don't forget to add it to SWTableViewCell.h

```
- (void)showUtilityButtonsAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Then call that method from within your -tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: delegate method.  For example:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    SWTableViewCell *cell = (SWTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell showUtilityButtonsAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I have a problem with your code. I show the utility buttons when a table view cell was selected but the cell scrolls two times.
I have an image left of the cell and when i select the cell sometimes scrolls well and i see the image at right, but sometimes scrolls two times and i have to click 2 times for close the cell.

Do you know what is happening? Thanks

Comment: Good point. I suppose I should have said that in my case I only had buttons on the left side of the cell and not on the right.  Without trying out anything I'd guess that setting the _cellState has something to do with the behavior you are seeing.  You might have to add code to determine the current scrollView contentOffset before setting it to show the buttons on one side or the other.